# Best way to convert an array of single property object literals to an array of just their values

Tags: javascript

I'd like to convert this:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]
```

into this:

```
['1','2','3']
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var objArray = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}];

var newArray = objArray.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.id;
});
```

Comment: I log the newArray but undefined ?

Comment: @jemz http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7xj3hkLe/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny it works if I use that example ,but when I request the id via jquery.ajax it will undefined after converting to array

Comment: @jemz you need to share the complete code for us to know the problem.. the problem stated by you in the question is resolved...

Comment: @ArunPJohny , it works now sorry my bad.

Comment: the reason that I have wrong typo in obj.id